# websocketpp connection failed with asio.system error code 10057

Tags: c++, websocket, openssl, boost-asio, websocket++

I use Websocket++ to connect to the deribit and bitmex exchange using websocket.
I wrote a wssclient class and i think there's no error in my code because i successfully connect to the deribit with address`wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v2`.

But somehow i couldn't connect to the bitmex with the address`wss://testnet.bitmex.com/realtime`. I found these address from their offical doc, and the debug message is following:

> [2020-02-17 00:50:35] [info] Error getting remote endpoint: asio.system:10057
>   [2020-02-17 00:50:35] [fail] WebSocket Connection Unknown -  /realtime 0 websocketpp.transport:9 Timer Expired
>   [2020-02-17 00:50:35] [error] handle_connect error: Timer Expired

And if more info is needed, just say it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Documentation can go stale, so the first thing you need to do is ensure wss://testnet.bitmex.com/realtime is a live address.  Consider monitoring the connection attempt with a packet-sniffing tool like Wireshark.

Comment: i will try it ,thanks!